# Search near by people by using Latitude & longitude IOS

Tags: ios, core-location

I am developing a chat app in iOS. In which a user can able to search near by people with a 1 kilo meter radius . 
On registration i stored the latitude and longitude of every user .
Now tell me how can i search people near by user within 1 kilo meter radius ??

thanks alot

Comment: It is possible using google map API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is directly you can't search users using Radios.Make following steps.

1. Send Latitude , Longitude and Radios information to Your Backend server using web service.
2. For your web service developer put query and get nearby users using your information.

Please refer following link:

[Geo Distance Search with MySQL](http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL)

Comment: I love MYSQL. MYSQL is the bigest tool ... love it

Answer (score 1):

You can use Haversine formula to calculate the appropriate distance between current latitude, longitude and target latitude, longitude.

`define DEG2RAD(degrees) (degrees * 0.01745327)`

`double currentLatitude = 40.727181;` // current latitude of logged in user
`double currentLongitude = -73.986786;` // current longitude of logged in user
`double destinationLatitude = 42.896578;` // latitude of target user
`double destinationLongitude = -75.784537;` // longitude of target user

//convert obtained latitude and longitude to RADS.
`double currentLatitudeRad = DEG2RAD(currentLatitude);`
`double currentLongitudeRad = DEG2RAD(currentLongitude);`
`double destinationLatitudeRad = DEG2RAD(destinationLatitude);`
`double destinationLongitudeRad = DEG2RAD(destinationLongitude);`

//Haversine Formula.
`distance  =  acos(sin(currentLatitudeRad) * sin(destinationLatitudeRad) + cos(currentLatitudeRad) * cos(destinationLatitudeRad) * cos(currentLongitudeRad - destinationLongitudeRad)) * 6880.1295896;`

The distance obtained here is in kilometers.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two locations using this method

`CLLocationDistance distanceInMeters = [locationA distanceFromLocation:locationB];`

Or calculate from backend(PHP developers) to find the distance, because basically they only store all lat,longs.(i think)

Comment: using this methode i have to check for every user in my database , ( for example if there are thousands of user then it takes a lot of time )